# Setting up subdomains on IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I've registered .no-ip.org, lets say  is lawl and its pointing to my server running Win 2k8 IIS7 with PHP.

CURRENTLY, my index.php checks `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and then `header()` to the right folder inside wwwroot.

This causes the url to look like lawl.no-ip.org/lawl when you go to lawl.no-ip.org. I would like to hide what folder the app is in from the user, but i dont know how to do this. 
So what i want is if you go to lawl.no-ip.org the url stays at lawl.no-ip.org. I have several no-ip.org domains and several folder (matching :D) inside wwwroot... how do i perform this magic? :D

I dont have a domain for it like .net or .com.

All i have in IIS is my Default Web Site.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create different web sites in IIS, and give each one a different virtual host name (for example, one site may have the host name lawl.no-ip.org and point to d:/somewhere/lawl.

Much easier than trying to do it in PHP.